# Testing Flask microservices using unittest module

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, microservices, python-unittest

I have developed a very basic microservice using Flask framework.

A method in the application looks like this

```
@app.route('/add, methods=['POST'])
def add_info():
    final = []
    try:
        info_obj.append(json.loads(request.data))
    ...
    return jsonify(final)
```

Now I am attempting to write Unittest for this method and other method in this microservice. I am using  `import unittest` to write my test.

Now here I am confused is how can I write tests to test the functionality of these http functions, which don't take regular argument of return regular results but rather fetch arguments from request data and return json based on that.

Is my approach correct? and if yes how can I test Microservices-like functionality using unittest module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely want unittesting, follow Patrick's guide [here](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/unit-testing-a-flask-application/). But I suggest using [PyTest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest). It's a breeze to get started. First you need a conftest.py. Then add your testfiles named test_... .py . The where your conftest is do `$ pytest`

Patrick has yet another PyTest + Flask guide [here](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/testing-a-flask-application-using-pytest/). You can view a demo of a conftest in a project [here](https://github.com/Abdur-rahmaanJ/shopyo/blob/dev/shopyo/conftest.py) on how to set up db etc and a test file [here](https://github.com/Abdur-rahmaanJ/shopyo/blob/dev/shopyo/modules/admin/test_user.py)